# Is there a mitzvah to escort a non-Jew?

Tags: gentiles, mitzvah, travel

There is a mitzvah to [escort a traveler](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/289767/jewish/Escorting-the-Traveler.htm) along their way. Does this mitzvah apply to escorting a non-Jewish traveler or guest as well?

Answer (score 2):

> “Avraham walked with them to escort them” - B’reishit 18:16
>
> “It is a positive commandment of Rabbinic origin to visit the sick,
>   comfort mourners, to prepare for a funeral, prepare a bride, accompany
>   guests, attend to all the needs of a burial, carry a corpse on one
>   shoulders, walk before the bier, mourn, dig a grave, and bury the
>   dead, and also to bring joy to a bride and groom and help them in all
>   their needs. These are deeds of kindness that one carries out with his
>   person that have no limit.
>
> Although all these mitzvot are of Rabbinic origin, they are included
>   in the Scriptural commandment Leviticus 19:18: "Love your neighbor as
>   yourself." That charge implies that whatever you would like other
>   people to do for you, you should do for your comrade in the Torah and
>   mitzvot.” - Hilchot Aveil 14 (the rest of the chapter is worth reading
>   as well)

Considering the people Avraham were escorting were by logic not bnei Yisrael, then yes, you should escort anyone(it seems even the stam goy). If they eat at your table and they say "thank you", tell them to please "thank God".

If you can, if they're not shomer sheva mitzvot bnei Noach, you should try to even pray for them similar to Avraham praying for the people of Sodom, Avimelech, etc.

Comment: I don't find your logic convincing in the slightest. Pre-mt-sinai is a different ballgame

Comment: It's the Rambam's logic post-mt-sinai.

" Accompanying them is greater than showing them hospitality. Our Sages said: "Whoever does not accompany them is considered as if he shed blood." "

Rambam says even for non-Jews as not to cause social issues.

Comment: Kidush-hashaem?
By the way, I did that once to a couple and they told me "God bless you". I'm pretty sure they were christian, would that be a problem of "ושם אלהים אחרים לא תזכירו לא ישמע על פיך" ?

Comment: A friend of mine was brought up Modern Orthodox but has drifted Yeshivishe due to his children. Once I asked him why does he always walk out of the office with the people he is interacting with---most of whom are not Jewish. His response was that he was attempting to emulate the prophet Abraham who did the same. This, of course, does not source the origin of such behavior, but it does seem to confirm that some Jews are convinced "escorting" people, Jew or Gentile, on their way, is important.